# How can i display the browser extension popup on all time even after clicking outside the extension popup or a next or new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I want to display my browser extension to display all time even if i click outside the extension popup or moving on to the another tab. it should only be closed when i click the close button inside my UI. I have made close button working but when i click outside the popup the popup is not displaying. what can be done for it to display it for all time like merlin Extension.

i have used this piece of code but it is not working

```
const customPopup = document.getElementById('popup-overlay');
const closeButton = document.getElementById('close-button');

// Attach an event listener to the document
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // Check if the clicked element is not part of the custom popup
  if (event.target !== customPopup && !customPopup.contains(event.target)) {
    // Prevent the default behavior (closing the popup)
   customPopup.style.display='block'
  }
});
customPopup.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Prevent the popup from being hidden when it is clicked
  event.stopPropagation();
});

// Attach an event listener to the close button
closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Close the custom popup when the close button is clicked
  customPopup.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Experts please help me to resolve this issues

Comment: The `action` popup can't do it. You can use chrome.sidePanel API or open a new window using chrome.windows.create or insert a DOM element with your UI inside the web page.